# How to append a contents of text file to a column in dataframe (pandas python)

Tags: python, pandas

There are bunch of text files in a directory. I want to add each text file to the last column in a row. Can this be achieved using pandas?

Eg:

**Directory1>**

1. File1.txt
2. File2.txt
3. File3.txt.... (Size of these files are close to 70KB)

**Dataframe:**

Column1      Column2      column3

Value1       Value2       (Trying to add File1.txt content here)

Is it possible using pandas? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the files to one file with a delimiter of your choice (make sure that the delimiter is not included in any of the text files), and then use `pd.read_csv()` to read the concatenated file.

Comment: I want File1.txt to be appended to column3 for row1 and similarly File2.txt to be appended to column3 of row2. I don't want to consolidate the files into one file.